# How to sum the digits of two integers?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

How could I use the following method to sum the integers of two numbers in a separate method? I'm trying to teach myself how to use overloaded methods but this is starting to confuse me. Thanks!

```
public static void sumNUmber(){
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = in.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: for example `12 = 3, 234 = 9`..??, your code works fine for the example i have written, what exactly you want

Comment: Kinda. I want to use the method I wrote to sum the value of two numbers in a separate method. so: 12(3) + 234(9) = 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take your core algorithm and put it into a single function and then call it twice, once for each number. For example,

```
// Core algorithm.
public static int sumDigits(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void sumNumber() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int numA = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter another number");
    int numB = in.nextInt();
    int totalDigits = sumDigits(numA) + sumDigits(numB);
    System.out.println(totalDigits);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(sumDigits(num));
    }

    public static int sumDigits(int num) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            sum += num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

**output**

```
Enter a number
234
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Merry Xmas :D

public int sumNumbers(int num) {
    int returnval;

    if (num < 10) { 
        return num;
    } else if (num < 100) {
        returnval = Math.floor(num/10) + (num%10);
    } else if (num < 1000) {
        returnval = Math.floor(num/100) + Math.floor(num/10) + (num%10);
    } //repeat as needed
    return 0;
}
```